# align text on the same line

Tags: html, text-align

I have an html which contains 1 label and 1 div box contains a text.

```
<label class="control-label col-xs-2">Name:</label>
<div class="col-xs-10">
  <strong>Test</strong>
</div>
```

But they seem not located on the same line. [Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/1169/) Could anyone help me how can I align them on the same line.

Thanks

Comment: Replace the `div` by a `span`?

Comment: `padding-top:5px` to your div..http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/1178/

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using bootstrap. Bootstrap already has default CSS for labels. so if you don't want that to happen remove the padding from the `<label>` element.

It will look like this:

```
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    /* padding-top: 5px; */
    text-align: right;
}
```

Hope this helps, Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for the code, you have to disable the padding-top like so: http://jsfiddle.net/ckxSs/1191/

Answer (score 0):

Apply `padding-top` to the `col-xs-10` in your CSS.

```
.col-xs-10 {
 padding-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: bad idea to modify bootstrap classes

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class="form-horizontal" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-xs-2">Name:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10">
      <strong>Test</strong>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap if you would like to have a horizontal form it is called inline.  So, if you change your "form-horizontal" to "form-inline" you will achieve that horizontal key/value pair. Below is the html that I changed to your code. I hope this is what you are looking for.

```
<div class="form-inline" role="form">
   <div class="form-group">
   <label for="control-label col-xs-12">Name:</label>
   <input type="text" class="form-control col-xs-10" id="control-label"placeholder="text here">           
   </div>
   </div>
```

In addition, you will notice that I have inserted an input tag.  This is what will allow site visitors to input the value.

Comment: Whoops, I just noticed that I messed up the columns but that should not interfere with your desired results and you can change that part.